# How can i attend a terminal input?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm asking you if there is a way to attend the input from command line before that the application (window) starts.

Here's the code if it could be useful:

```
package classi.luca;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 extends JPanel {
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);            // call superclass to make panel display correctly
        System.out.print("Do you want to visualize Circle data or Rectangle data? ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String figure_init = in.next();
        FiguresInit figure = new FiguresInit();  // create a FiguresInt variable
        switch (figure_init) {
            case "Circle": figure.initCircle(g); // Initialize a Circle from FiguresInit
                break;
            case "Rectangle": figure.initRectangle(g);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test1 panel = new Test1();
        FrameClass fr = new FrameClass("Disegno e Area del Cerchio"); // Inizialize a  drawing panel of  FrameClass Type

        fr.init(panel); 
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to attend the `System.in` scanning before opening the app window?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the System.in part to you main method and pass the value to your Test1 constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Do you want to visualize Circle data or Rectangle data? ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String figure_init = in.next();
    FiguresInit figure = new FiguresInit();  // create a FiguresInt variable
    Test1 panel = new Test1(figure);
    //...
```

Your constructor will look something like this:

```
Test1(FiguresInit figure) {
  this.figure = figure;
  // other init stuff
}
```

Comment: Ok. And how can i pass  `figure` to `Test1`? @Burkhard

Comment: @LucaPierri Look at his code, he is already doing that (and wrote that in his sentence above the code).